# Antonym of copypasta

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there any antonym for "copypasta", preferably in the context of computer programming?

I can't think of anything more concise than "written from scratch".

Neither [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copypasta) or [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=copypasta) lists any antonyms, though the latter has a self-demonstrating entry of what copypasta is, with the top definition duplicated twice.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question about *copypasta*! I have never heard of it until three minutes ago. :) It's a brilliant coinage.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe I could do a copypasta of Yoichi Oishi's question ;) http://english.stackexchange.com/q/113155/1420

Comment: This is an excellent etymology question if ever I saw one. Think about it. Yoichi doesn't ask about its meaning but an English equivalent to a Japanese neologism; *copypasta* was a suggested answer. BIG difference IMO.

Comment: Copypasta as I understand it has a very specific meaning which is covered in [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/copypasta), which is different from what Wiktionary and Urban Dict have to say. I don't think there's really an antonym for it - if there were, it would basically refer to everything else that isn't copypasta. Like any of the comments on this question, or your question, etc... I suspect you're really asking about "text that is created to be reused" - which isn't quite the same thing as copypasta. (Copypasta isn't necessarily *made* for reuse - it becomes it afterward.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Original*** is the antonym of *copypasta*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OC for "original content".

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OC) also defines it as "original character". But in the context of chan threads and memes, the antonym of "copypasta" is "OC" for "original content".

Comment: I agree with the answer but isn't it effectively the same as the above?

Comment: Literally, "copypasta" means "copy & paste". But it's message board slang. "OC" is the message board slang term for "original".